# Get reference from WeakReference java

Tags: java, android

Is it same ways to use weekreference?

first way: in the contstructor create WeakReference obj and immediately get my Callbacks obj.

```
private static final class LoadImageFromUrl extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    private Callbacks mCallbacks;

    public LoadImageFromUrl(String url, Callbacks callbacks) {
        mCallbacks = new WeakReference<>(callbacks).get();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mCallbacks.successfully(bitmap);
    }
```

second way: in the contstructor create WeakReference obj and get my Callbacks obj when i need something do with it.

```
private static final class LoadImageFromUrl extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    private WeakReference<Callbacks> mCallbacks;

    public LoadImageFromUrl(String url, Callbacks callbacks) {
        mCallbacks = new WeakReference<>(callbacks);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mCallbacks.get().successfully(bitmap);
    }
```

I think it similar ways, but not exactly.

Comment: The first way won't work at all.  The second one will -- as long as you have another strong reference to `callbacks`, or else you'll get a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the second version with the addition of a check whether the callback still exists.

```
private static final class LoadImageFromUrl extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    private WeakReference<Callbacks> mCallbacks;

    public LoadImageFromUrl(String url, Callbacks callbacks) {
        mCallbacks = new WeakReference<>(callbacks);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Callbacks cb = mCallbacks.get();
        if (cb != null) cb.successfully(bitmap);
    }
}
```

But that is a legitimate yet dangerous implementation because the caller needs to keep a strong reference. And that not always the case especially with callbacks. For example

```
void onCreate(..) {
    ... 
    new LoadImageFromUrl(new Callbacks() { void foo() .... }).execute();
    ...
}
```

will fail because nothing keeps a strong reference to the anonymous inner implementation. And that's a common way to implement callbacks.

Semi related: Make sure not to make sure not to extend the `LoadImageFromUrl` task as inner class because that will cause it to leak the containing class due to the implicit `ContainingClass.this` reference in every inner class. That would defeat the purpose of weak references.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, it is useless to make a WeakReference because you get the value into it immediately, to store it into a strong reference (the field of your class)

In the second case, it is a real weak reference : if there is no other strong reference of your callback, it could be garbage collected. So `mCallbacks.get()` could return null in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to keep your `callback`s as `WeakReference`? Have you read anything about `Strong`/`Weak`/`Soft`/`PhantomReferences`?

I would advice you to get some knowledge about it and then rethinking your solution. [Example article](https://www.rallydev.com/blog/engineering/java-references-strong-soft-weak-phantom)